# React-native and expo-print

Tags: react-native, expo

I hope your help, I have a problem with the exposure. Well, I am developing an application and I want my user to be able to download a pdf based on the products they want. However, I have a problem, I am using expo-print and I have a lot of difficulties with the "printAsync" function, I save it as a PDF file and I get the following error when I want to open the file:"file format error. Cannot open file"

[image]

Comment: I think it would be very helpful to show us some code. For now the error seems not to fit your intention. Since you don't want to edit anything, there might be an error in a function call or a config. And make sure to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry friend I'm not so much to consult in forums